# Pivoting space delimited varchar to multiple rows (name - value pairs)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a large number of rows in an SQL Server 2008 db

For each row I have 3 columns that I care about

A typical row looks like this:

```
AccountNumber    | basecode                      | subcode
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9689787209368901 | AQTXG AQTXG AQTXG AQTXG ACC5Z | ZQ596 ZQ596 ZQ596 ZQ655 ZC655
```

I need an SQL query that turns it into the following:

```
AccountNumber      |    basecode| subcode
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9689787209368901   |    AQTXG   | ZQ596
9689787209368901   |    AQTXG   | ZQ596
9689787209368901   |    AQTXG   | ZQ596
9689787209368901   |    AQTXG   | ZQ655
9689787209368901   |    ACC5Z   | ZC655
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server, you can use a recursive query to split the data. IN this query, you can have an unknown number of items that are split with the space (`' '`), if your delimiter changes then this is easy to alter. Your query would be similar to this:

```
;with cte (AccountNumber, basecodeItem, basecode, subcodeItem, subcode) as
(
  select AccountNumber,
    cast(left(basecode, charindex(' ',basecode+' ')-1) as varchar(50)) basecodeItem,
         stuff(basecode, 1, charindex(' ',basecode+' '), '') basecode,
    cast(left(subcode, charindex(' ',subcode+' ')-1) as varchar(50)) subcodeItem,
         stuff(subcode, 1, charindex(' ',subcode+' '), '') subcode
  from yourtable
  union all
  select AccountNumber,
    cast(left(basecode, charindex(' ',basecode+' ')-1) as varchar(50)) basecodeItem,
    stuff(basecode, 1, charindex(' ',basecode+' '), '') basecode,
    cast(left(subcode, charindex(' ',subcode+' ')-1) as varchar(50)) subcodeItem,
    stuff(subcode, 1, charindex(' ',subcode+' '), '') subcode
  from cte
  where basecode > '' or subcode > ''
)
select AccountNumber, basecodeItem, subcodeitem
from cte;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a477c/2)

The result is:

```
|    ACCOUNTNUMBER | BASECODEITEM | SUBCODEITEM |
-------------------------------------------------
| 9689787209368900 |        AQTXG |       ZQ596 |
| 9689787209368900 |        AQTXG |       ZQ596 |
| 9689787209368900 |        AQTXG |       ZQ596 |
| 9689787209368900 |        AQTXG |       ZQ655 |
| 9689787209368900 |        ACC5Z |       ZC655 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Rows are allway filled with 5 sequences, this should work

```
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,1,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,1,5) as SC
from @test
UNION ALL
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,7,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,7,5) as SC
from @test
UNION ALL
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,13,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,13,5) as SC
from @test
UNION ALL
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,19,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,19,5) as SC
from @test
UNION ALL
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,25,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,25,5) as SC
from @test
```

could be wrapped as

```
Select * from
(
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,1,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,1,5) as SC,0 as Sequence
from @test
UNION ALL
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,7,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,7,5) as SC,1
from @test
UNION ALL
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,13,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,13,5) as SC,2
from @test
UNION ALL
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,19,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,19,5) as SC,3
from @test
UNION ALL
Select TableAccountNumber,SubString(basecode,25,5) as BC,SubString(Subcode,25,5) as SC,4
from @test
) a
order by TableAccountNumber,Sequence
```